# Changing values in pandas columns: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame error

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this pandas df named **matches**, which has two columns "Thread" and "Current email". "Current email" was copied from another df called **df**:

```
matches['Current email'] = df['description']
```

Thread has only two values: **thread** and **not thread**. So if the email is a thread I want to change the "Current email" value with same index to an 8 (actually to another thing, but for simplicity of understanding an 8).

```
for index,value in matches['Thread'].iteritems():
  if value=='not thread':
    pass 
  else:
    matches.iloc[index]['Current email'] = 8
```

After running this the warning **/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame** comes up.

I tried things like:

```
matches['Current email'] = df['description'].copy()
```

What is even wierder is that the same code worked for other data.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
filter_thread = matches['Thread'] != 'not thread'
matches.loc[filter_thread, 'Current email'] = 8
```